# Keyframes of linked rig not getting saved

Tags: keyframes, linked-data, saving

I have linked a rig into my scene where I want to pose it in.
I made a library override to the rig to make it posable.

So far I am able to pose the linked rig, I made keyframes and saved my file.

When I reopen my file the pose and the keyframes are gone and the rig is in default pose.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

My rig had some rests of animation/actions on it.
Deleting them solved the issue.